# Why is my iFrame working on localhost, but not in production?

Tags: iframe, dev-to-production

I have several iFrames on a page at the same time. Most of them work the way you would expect; they display if the `X-Frame-Options` value of the target page allows it, and don't if they don't. But a few will come up just fine when viewing them on localhost, but will suddenly stop working when the code is moved to a production server. It can't be a case of the `X-Frame-Options` allowing one but prohibiting the other; the inconsistent pages don't have an `X-Frame-Options` value, so there shouldn't be any restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind; a quick look at the console on the production server reveals that it was due to Firefox blocking "mixed active content", a protection which seems to be relaxed in a local environment.